# Why doesn't $\arccos x = -\tfrac12\sqrt{3}$ have any solutions?

Tags: trigonometry

I have this exercise with an unclear answer. The question is this:
$$\arccos x = -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\,.$$

The answer is this:
$$\begin{gather*}
\varphi(x)= \arccos x\\
V_\varphi = [0,\pi]\\
-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\notin V_\varphi\,.
\end{gather*}
$$

can someone this a bit more to me? How does this prove that there are no solutions?

Comment: Is the question "Does it exist a (real) $x$ such that arccos$(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}?$" ?

Comment: No need to limit yourself to real $x$. There's no complex $x$ with that property either. (In both real and complex numbers, that is true if you take the standard primary branch.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Domain of $\arccos(x)$ is $[-1,1]$ (not $\mathbb{R})$, so the range of values is $[0,\pi]$, but $\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}<0$, so it isn't in range.

Answer (score 8):

As a couple of others have already pointed out, $-\sqrt{3}/2$ is simply not in the range of the arccosine.  Here's an explanation as to why that's true.

Here's the graph of the cosine function over the interval $[-\pi,2\pi]$:

[image]

The issue is that this function is *not* one-to-one.  As a result, we must restrict it to an appropriate domain where it *is* one-to-one in order to talk a about a restricted inverse function.  Conventionally, the interval $[0,\pi]$ is chosen, which yields something like the following:

[image]

Now, the inverse of this restricted version of the cosine is what we know as the arccosine and its graph looks like so:

[image]

Of course, the domain and range have flipped - thus, $-\sqrt{3}/2$ (or any other negative number) is not in the range!

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

Do you know that the range of $f(x)=\arccos x$? It is not $\Bbb R$.